# YouTube java api v3: how to pause or interrupt ongoing videdo upload

Tags: java, upload, youtube-api

I am migrating from Youtube Java API v2 to v3 in an application that is doing YT upload. In my application I need to explicitly pause the video upload in situations where all the network capacity is needed for a more important use, but I can't find a corresponding pause() or resume() methods in v3 classes. Even forcibly canceling the transfer and re-starting it later would be an acceptable workaround.

I have browsed through the javadocs and some of the code too and can't find a way to accomplish this. It seems the only way is to do some manual overrides to the classes that do the upload itself. Now I am asking that has anybody done this already?

I am using google apis version 1.19

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Answering to myself:

Although Youtube API V3 itself supports putting upload temporarily on hold and continuing it later, the Java API does not. The API assumes always uploading in one synchronous call.

Adding pause/resume support requires one to rewrite the API partially.

If someone is interested, I'd be happy to share my work.